# Codeigniter POST/GET variables and $this->input->post

Tags: php, ajax, database, codeigniter

I have an issue with post variables in Codeigniter, for now I fixed it, but I'm not sure if this is fine, in other words, I'd really like to know why I had issue only on hosting server, not on local.

The problem:
I wanted more secure script so I replaced $_POST/$_GET with $this->input->post and $this->input->get, like in this example:

```
if(!empty($this->input->get('endDate'))){
   $data['datepicker'] = $this->input->get('thisDate');
}
```

this was all working fine on my localhost, but I assume it is wrong way, as when I deployed to the hosting server, I've got ajax parse error from [validation engine](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine) that I'm using, I couldn't log in the system, getting all the time ajax parse error, and somehow figured out that whenever I checked if empty$this->input->post('var) or the same with get, was wrong.

I have checked the input class from Codeigniter and figured out, that $this->input->post is returning true/false, so I changed the scripts in the format like this:

```
if(!($this->input->get('endDate'))){
   $data['datepicker'] = $this->input->get('thisDate');
}
```

this worked fine.
I'm still wondering - why the code worked on the localhost, but it didn't on the server or what is the best way to check if the POST/GET variable is empty or not.Seems I really miss something out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that checking for `empty($this->post->get('var'))` will always return false, no matter if the POST/GET exists, so it might be for that reason only.   -  So i'm not sure why you got the error on a different environment, but the first statement is wrong, it's exactly like writing `if(true)`

Also, I'd check for a strong assertion of false for inputs, You never know when you might need a zero as an input and if you're used to this practice, you might get an accidental false.

Comment: Will leave the mistery how it worked on my local out, thank you for confirming the first part was wrong. for checking if empty, I'm using it only when it is really safe.